# Perl + Bash one-liner to sum bytes sent from Apache log files: Can this be right?

Tags: apache, perl, bash, sum

A client has requested their outgoing bandwidth usage.

Our Apache logs have lines like the following, where **36618** represents the outgoing request size in bytes:

`111.111.111.11 - - - foo.org [23/May/2014:01:00:15 -0400] 0`**36618**`"GET /baz/bar.html HTTP/1.1" 200 3734 "http://foo.org/baz/bar.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36"`

I constructed this (mostly) Perl one-liner to sum up all of those numbers by grabbing it via regex, and appending it to an empty array, then dumping the array delimited by '+' through the Bash Calculator. (the below line ultimately gets piped through `|paste -sd+|bc`  The log file is fed into the below line on standard input.

`@BYTES = (); while(<>) { push(@BYTES, $1) if ( $_ =~ qr/] (?:\d+|-) (\d+)/) }; foreach(@BYTES) { print "$_\n" }`

However, I am seeing much higher usage than I would expect, multiple gigabytes in just a few days.  That cannot be right.  What's wrong here?

**UPDATE** See my comment below, I had the wrong field, the field I chose was time taken to serve request in microseconds, bound to be higher than size of request in bytes.

Comment: I have the wrong field, I apologize!  I had the time taken to serve request in microseconds!  Sorry!  in this case it should be 3734.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I am seeing much higher usage than I would expect, multiple gigabytes in just a few days. That cannot be right. What's wrong here?

It might be that you're looking at wrong field, check your `LogFormat` in webserver configuration

> 111.111.111.11 - - - foo.org [23/May/2014:01:00:15 -0400] 0 <strike>36618</strike> "GET /baz/bar.html HTTP/1.1" 200 **3734** "http://foo.org/baz/bar.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36"

Comment: This is the correct answer, I figured it out before this post, but Ill award it to you since you are in fact completely right.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal no need to use `sum` => `perl -nE '$s += $_ for /] (?:\d+|-) (\d+)/ END{ say $s }' logfile`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
cat file.log | sed 's/"http.*//' | awk '{print $NF}' | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Comment: Not bad, but I cannot guarantee every line will have the referrer beginning with http.  Also you can shorten this to `sed 's/"http.*//' file.log | awk '{print $NF}' | paste -sd+ | bc`

Comment: Right, referer is not guaranteed. Use `grep -o "HTTP/1.*" file.log  | awk '{print $3}' | paste -sd+ | bc`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
sum=$( perl -anE '$sum += $F[8]} END {say $sum' file.log )
```

Assumes the size is always in the 9th field of a line.

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one-liner to pull from the correct field:

```
perl -ne '$s += $1 if /"\s+\d+\s+(\d+)\s+"/ }{ print "$s\n"' access_log
```

Comment: How do you get away with `}{` ? I was thinking it's the -n, but doesnt that just put a while (<>) { } around the code, is that why? so this evaluates to `while (<>) {$s += $1 if /"\s+\d+\s+(\d+)\s+"/ } { print $s\n }` ?

Comment: `-e 'EXPR1; }{ EXPR2'` is a perl oneliner shortcut for `-e 'EXPR1; END { EXPR2 }'`.  Unfortunately, I don't know where it's documented in perldoc, so I can't point to a reference.